# Real Analysis: Convex

Tags: real-analysis, functions

$a\geq0$ and $b>0$. Show that $\phi(t) = (a+bt)^p$ is convex on $[0, \infty)$ for $1\leq p< \infty$.

Can I just take the derivative and show that is increasing like a calc 1 problem. Or can I just prove that the second derivative is non negative?

Comment: For the first: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Second_Derivative_of_Convex_or_Concave_Function              For the just: differentiate and the conclusion follows from the first one.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Maths.SE. Thank you for your question! It is good practice on this site to add a bit of information on the context your question came up in, and to share your own work on it. It's also fine if you state that you're completely lost -- the information is helpful for answerers to gauge their answer on. For more information on asking a good question on this site, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/43351).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $a \ge 0$ and $b \gt 0$, the function $\phi(t)$ can be viewed as the composition of two functions on $[0,\infty)$, an increasing linear one and the special case $\phi_0(t) = t^p$ for $1 \le p \lt \infty$ (i.e. case $a=0,b=1$).

The suggested approach of taking derivatives is fine.  There probably is little difference between showing the first derivative is (weakly) increasing and showing the second derivative is non-negative.  Let's look at the special case $\phi_0(t)$ to see why.

$$ \frac{d\phi_0(t)}{dt} = p t^{p-1} $$

For the boundary case $p=1$, the result above is a constant first derivative, so it is not strictly increasing, only weakly so.  However I would interpret "convexity" in this problem to allow linearity, i.e. weak inequality in the definition of convex function.

If $p \gt 1$, then the derivative above is increasing "by inspection".  If we wish to be more rigorous, there's no better method than appealing to the second derivative:

$$ \frac{d^2\phi_0(t)}{dt^2} = p(p-1) t^{p-2} $$

Again assuming $p \gt 1$, this second derivative is clearly positive for $t \in (0,\infty)$, so the (strict) convexity can be established by the standard Mean Value Theorem argument (cf. [Thm. 1](http://galletue.ing-mat.udec.cl/~camilo/material_udec/icm/2011-1/Opti%20II/material%20web/convex%283%29.pdf) of this course handout).